# How to get CPU information in Linux kernel Module?

Tags: cpu, proc

I looked into my kernel source and found the following defines in **kerneldir/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h**:

```
extern void cpu_detect(struct cpuinfo_x86 *c);
```

I attempted to use this in my out-of-tree kernel module using this code:

```
#include <asm/processor.h>
struct cpuinfo_x86 cpu;
cpu_detect(&cpu);
if(cpu.x86_model == 28) // Intel Atom
{
    // do stuff
}
```

When I build my source code, I get the following warnings:

```
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "cpu_detect" [<my-kernel-module-path>.ko] undefined!
```

Is there a better way to get CPU information from kernel space within my module? If the way I am doing it is correct, is there any special linking options I need to pass so that I can get the object code?

Answer (score 1):

```
static int cpu_info_print(void){
    unsigned int cpu = 0;
    struct cpuinfo_x86 *c;
    for_each_online_cpu(cpu)
    {
        const char *vendor = NULL;
        c = &cpu_data(cpu);
        if (c->x86_vendor < X86_VENDOR_NUM) {
            vendor = "Unknown";
        } else {
            if (c->cpuid_level >= 0)
                vendor = c->x86_vendor_id;
        }

        if (vendor && !strstr(c->x86_model_id, vendor))
            pr_cont("%s ", vendor);

        if (c->x86_model_id[0])
            pr_cont("%s", c->x86_model_id);
        else
            pr_cont("%d86", c->x86);

        pr_cont(" (family: 0x%x, model: 0x%x", c->x86, c->x86_model);

        if (c->x86_stepping || c->cpuid_level >= 0)
            pr_cont(", stepping: 0x%x)\n", c->x86_stepping);
        else
            pr_cont(")\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any information on **cpu_detect**, but searching for **print_cpu_info** (also present in that header) found a stackoverflow question, which has a solution:

Use a function pointer to `kallsyms_lookup_name("print_cpu_info")`, as the function is not exported for modules (only core kernel use)

[How my custom module on linux 3.2.28 can make a call to print_cpu_info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691123/how-my-custom-module-on-linux-3-2-28-can-make-a-call-to-print-cpu-info)